# Get last 2 lines from multiple files

Tags: awk

I can get the last 2 lines of multiple files using `tail` command like

```
$ tail -n 2 file1.txt file2.txt
==> file1.txt <==
3,2,1,1
8,8,4,4

==> file2.txt <==
B1 987 6545
C1 876 5434
$
```

But I need to format the above output to get it like below

```
3,2,1,1 file1.txt
8,8,4,4 file1.txt
B1 987 6545 file2.txt
C1 876 5434 file2.txt
```

Is there way to get the above output only using awk?

I tried something like below, but it works for only last line.

```
$ awk ' { if(FNR==1 && NR!=1)  print p,f; p=$0;f=FILENAME }  END { print p,f } ' file1.txt file2.txt
8,8,4,4 file1.txt
C1 876 5434 file2.txt
$
```

How to expand it for last 2 or n lines?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following answer represents a **POSIX compliant** solution that works with any awk. As you can see from [Ed Morton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55150103/8344060), GNU awk can make life a bit easier.*

---

**the last two lines:** The easiest for two lines would be the following:

```
awk '(FNR==1) && f!="" { print t1,f; print t2,f }
     (FNR==1) { f=FILENAME }
     { t1=t2; t2=$0 }
     END { print t1, f; print t2, f}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

The program introduces the variables `f` which stores the filename and `t1` and `t2` representing the last two lines of the file. Every time we enter a new non-empty file `(FNR==1)` or hit the end of the program, we use these variables to do the printing.

This method, however, has a main flaw:

> Files with a single line create wrong results

**the last `n` lines:** If you want to expand this to the last `n` lines, you'll have to make use of an array `t`. Furthermore, if you want to be able to handle files with less than `n` lines, you'll have to keep track of how many lines the file has (`fnr`). The latter variable `fnr` will always equal `FNR` of the previous line at the beginning of the program cycle.

Also, it will become a bit messy, if you want to use the swap principle

```
awk -v n=2 '(FNR==1) && f!="" { for(i=1; i <= (fnr < n ? fnr : n); ++i) print t[i],f }
            (FNR==1) { f=FILENAME }
            { fnr = FNR }
            (fnr <= n) { t[fnr] = $0 }                
            (fnr >  n) { for(i=1; i < n; ++i) t[i] = t[i+1]; t[n]=$0 }
            END { for(i=1; i <= (fnr < n ? fnr : n); ++i) print t[i],f }
           ' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

You can clean it up a bit if you want to get rid of the swapping and use modulo calculations (cfr [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55150103/8344060)):

```
awk -v n=2 'function tail { 
               for(i=1+(fnr < n ? n-fnr : 0); i<=n; ++i) print t[(fnr+i)%n],f  
            }
            (FNR==1) && f!="" { tail() }
            (FNR==1) { f=FILENAME }
            { fnr = FNR; t[FNR%n] = $0 }
            END { tail() }
           ' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Which, in GNU awk is just simply:

```
awk -v n=2 '{ t[FNR%n] = $0 }
            ENDFILE { 
              for(i=1+(FNR < n ? n-FNR : 0); i<=n; ++i) print t[(FNR+i)%n],FILENAME                
            }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: can ````for(i=1; i <= (fnr < n ? fnr : n); ++i) print t[i],f```` be wrapped in a function?

Comment: @stack0114106 `function foo() { for(i=1; i <= (fnr < n ? fnr : n); ++i) print t[i],f }`.

Comment: yes.. great research and thanks for exploring all the variants.. ENDFILE is not working for me.. I'll accept your answer..

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE:

```
$ awk '{p2=p1; p1=$0} ENDFILE{print p2, FILENAME ORS p1, FILENAME }' file1 file2
3,2,1,1 file1
8,8,4,4 file1
B1 987 6545 file2
C1 876 5434 file2
```

In general for any number `n` of lines:

```
$ awk -v n=2 '{p[NR%n]=$0} ENDFILE{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print p[(NR+i)%n], FILENAME}' file1 file2
3,2,1,1 file1
8,8,4,4 file1
B1 987 6545 file2
C1 876 5434 file2
```

Add a `delete p` after printing and/or do whatever else you like to handle files with fewer than `n` lines.

Comment: Using ENDFILE really makes life easier. This should become part of POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest solution, but it's an `awk` one-liner as requested:

```
awk '{if (FNR==1 && NR!=1) {print secondLast" "prevFname ORS last" "prevFname} prevFname=FILENAME;last=$0} {secondLast=prevLine;prevLine=$0} END {print secondLast" "FILENAME ORS last" "FILENAME}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Note that this will become unwieldy as the number of lines you want increases.